# How to filter view query results based on reduce value (and not just on key)

Tags: couchdb

Using map/reduce functions only (not Mango),and the following example from the documentation, using the map and reduce functions below One may obtain the number of unique labels:

**Documents return by the view**

```
{"total_rows":9,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"3525ab874bc4965fa3cda7c549e92d30","key":"bike","value":null},
{"id":"3525ab874bc4965fa3cda7c549e92d30","key":"couchdb","value":null},
{"id":"53f82b1f0ff49a08ac79a9dff41d7860","key":"couchdb","value":null},
{"id":"da5ea89448a4506925823f4d985aabbd","key":"couchdb","value":null},
{"id":"3525ab874bc4965fa3cda7c549e92d30","key":"drums","value":null},
{"id":"53f82b1f0ff49a08ac79a9dff41d7860","key":"hypertext","value":null},
{"id":"da5ea89448a4506925823f4d985aabbd","key":"music","value":null},
{"id":"da5ea89448a4506925823f4d985aabbd","key":"mustache","value":null},
{"id":"53f82b1f0ff49a08ac79a9dff41d7860","key":"philosophy","value":null}
]}
```

**Map function**

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.name && doc.tags) {
        doc.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
            emit(tag, 1);
        });
    }
}
```

**Reduce function**

```
function(keys, values) {
    return sum(values);
}
```

**Response with grouping**

```
{"rows":[
{"key":"bike","value":1},
{"key":"couchdb","value":3},
{"key":"drums","value":1},
{"key":"hypertext","value":1},
{"key":"music","value":1},
{"key":"mustache","value":1},
{"key":"philosophy","value":1}
]}
```

Now my question is, using map/reduce views only (not Mango) how can I query the view to **only select rows having a specific value following reduce (for example "3")**. It looks like all view parameters focus on filtering based on the key, but I need to filter based on value. Ideally, being able to also use greater than, lesser than for reduce value filtering would also be great.

The ability to filter based on the value is essential for scenarios like the one above, but also for more advanced scenarios involving linked documents.  Of course, I am not interested in filtering in memory in the application layer since in real world scenarios, the result set would be much larger than a dozen lines.

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible. Sorting is also only key based.

Comment: This is what I have started to believe as well, thanks for helping!